# Trigonometric inequality solving

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How to solve this inequality $\left|\dfrac{\cos 2x + 3}{\cos x}\right|\geq 4$ ?

I tried to consider 2 cases:

1) When $\cos 2x \geq 0$ and $0<\cos x<1$

2) $\cos 2x\leq 0$ and $-1 < \cos x < 0$.

But I think that's wrong.

Comment: Change $\cos(2x)$ to $2\cos^2(x)-1$ and square both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$

$$\frac{\cos2x+3}{\cos x}=\frac{2\cos^2x-1+3}{\cos x}=2\left(\cos x+\frac1{\cos x}\right)$$

If $\displaystyle \cos x>0, \cos x+\frac1{\cos x} \ge 2\sqrt{\cos x\cdot\frac1{\cos x}}=2$ (using A.M.$\ge$ G.M.)

I leave the case $\cos x<0$ for you

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible to solve $\cos x + \frac{1}{\cos x} \geq  2$? $\cos x$ values must be from -1 to 1, or not?

Comment: @AlexanderSide, what is the range of $\frac1{\cos x}?$

Comment: (-inf; -1] U [1; inf). But need to solve $\cos^{2} x   + 1 \geq 2\cos x$ if $\cos x \neq 0$.

Comment: @AlexanderSide, try putting some known values of $\cos x$ like $0,1,\frac12$ etc.